# npm not being able to find a file - sshpk-conv, errno -2 - Thinkster Angular

Tags: json, node.js, angular, npm

I'm currently working through the thinkster.io tutorial and after building the backend successfully I went on to programming the frontend. I'm using a VM configured automatically using vagrant, I access it through ssh and got a part of my local HDD synced with part of the VM's HDD (in case that is relevant).

I started off with:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install build-essential
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Then browsed into the frontend-folder (where the package.json is located) and ran

```
npm install
```

Just to be greeted by this error:

```
npm WARN deprecated angular-cli@1.0.0-beta.15: angular-cli has been renamed to @angular/cli. Please update your dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated node-uuid@1.4.8: Use uuid module instead
npm WARN deprecated tough-cookie@2.2.2: ReDoS vulnerability parsing Set-Cookie https://nodesecurity.io/advisories/130
ang2-conduit@0.0.0 /vagrant/thinkster/angular2-realworld-example-app
├── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/compiler@2.0.0
└── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/core@2.0.0

npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.6 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@4.4.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@4.4.6 requires a peer of @angular/core@4.4.6 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.4.10 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.4.10 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.4.10 requires a peer of @angular/common@2.4.10 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.4.10 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.4.10 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/platform-server@2.4.10 requires a peer of @angular/platform-browser@2.4.10 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/tsc-wrapped@4.4.6 requires a peer of typescript@^2.1.5 but none was installed.
npm WARN string-replace-loader@1.3.0 requires a peer of webpack@1 || 2 || 3 but none was installed.
npm WARN tsickle@0.21.6 requires a peer of typescript@^2.1.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.0 requires a peer of webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 requires a peer of @angular/platform-server@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm WARN @angular/compiler-cli@0.6.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@2.0.2 but none was installed.
npm ERR! Linux 4.9.0-3-amd64
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.11.4
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! path /vagrant/thinkster/angular2-realworld-example-app/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/sshpk/bin/sshpk-conv
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall chmod

npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/vagrant/thinkster/angular2-realworld-example-app/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/sshpk/bin/sshpk-conv'
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod '/vagrant/thinkster/angular2-realworld-example-app/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/node_modules/http-signature/node_modules/sshpk/bin/sshpk-conv'
npm ERR! enoent This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! enoent and is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /vagrant/thinkster/angular2-realworld-example-app/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

I tried various things that I found online but none seem to have helped. I'm not too familiar with npm, therefore I'm struggling to get it to work. Can anyone help?

This is the *package.json:*

```
{
  "name": "ang2-conduit",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "marked": "^0.3.6",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/marked": "0.0.28",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.5",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "3.13.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.2"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on a vagrant VM I suppose? My guess is that you are storing the project in a shared folder with a windows host. I see the module failing is request, which has failed me on numerous occasions either directly on windows or in shared folders.

Your best bet, if you are really on a vagrant VM, is to mount a VM folder onto node_modules. This will make sure symbolic links and the links work as intended since they will remain on the same system.

To achieve this, SSH into the VM, and run those lines:

```
sudo mkdir -p /app_node_modules
sudo mount --bind /app_node_modules /vagrant/thinkster/angular2-realworld-example-app/node_modules
```

You have to know that the npm install is performing all tasks on a unix based system, while the folder hosting the files is hosted on a different kind of system which has different capabilities.

Found a possible workaround on [this sshpk-conv issue](https://github.com/joyent/node-sshpk/issues/16)

> I had a similar issue with npm 4.1.2, and it disappeared after
>   updating to latest 4.6.1. There is also a workaround for the issue:
>   npm install --no-bin-links; in this case, npm won't attempt to chmod
>   these files.

Comment: I'm using a Mac and the VM is running in VirtualBox, but is set up and configured using vagrant. So it should be a unix-system on both sides. Does that make a difference?

Comment: They are both unix based but the VM might not be able to manage the rights accordingly. I remember having to tweak the rights of the folder when I worked with Mac on a PHP based software... Please open up the complete log, and see exactly where it fails. My guess is that a symbolic link was to be created, the system didn't return an error, but then the file doesn't exist... But I'm just pitching in the dark...

Comment: Sounds very reasonable, thank you! Here's the gist https://gist.github.com/lterfloth/70303d9617125cb29300a1bdec26964e

Comment: The install process seems to stop on the extraction of the file. I've pointed to an issue where people were having the same problem but the file was getting extracted correctly first... Since it is a bin, could it be your anti-virus blocking it?

Comment: Disabling antivirus and the firewall did not change the result, sadly...

Comment: ok, I've added the steps to mount the node_modules in my answer. This should be useful to test if the problem comes from install/npm/node etc or if it comes from the filesystem differences like I am guessing. Although this could prove useful, this will prevent you to get full code completion in your IDE since the modules will not sit on your system and won't be accessible...

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the dependencies and do a npm install of those dependencies with -g parameter or --global and then try running the npm run command.